# NetSuite: popup message on Quote

Tags: popup, netsuite, quote

We are looking for a code that could popup a message when a user view a quote, if the customer on a saved search, the message shows otherwise no message showing.

I'm not a developer but I feel the logic is simple so it shouldn't be a complex code. I searched online a little bit and randomly come up with something:

```
define([], function () {
    function showMessage(context) {
        var message = "This customer does not have a contact information, please make sure you have the payment information on hand and you could process the payment once the Quote is being Converted"
        var searchresult = contaxt.nlapiLoadRecord(Transaction, customsearch387)({
        "searchID": "customsearch387"
        });

        if (customsearch387){
            alert(message):
        }
  }

    return {
        pageInit: showMessage
  };
```

});

Could anyone educate me a little bit on my script? I couldn't use it since it gave me error when i upload it to netsuite.

Thanks,
Yiting

Comment: The one person's answer of using a workflow is accurate. You should be able to do this there and because you do not know code that would make the most sense. You are combining syntax from SuiteScript 1.0 and 2.0 in your code which is probably why it won't save. Try a workflow action for message and if you have issues with that, post a new question with what you try and the results

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a workflow instead since your not familiar with scripting. It might be a bit easier for you.

Comment: Thanks dcrs! i have tried the workflow but it doesn't show messages when user view it. "show message" is available for "before user edit" which shows when user click Edit as the earliest time point. we'll need it to show as soon as page loads.